# How to combine cmidrule of the booktabs-package with siunitx correctly?

Tags: siunitx, booktabs

After rewriting this post multiple times, I'll just write it like this:

- How can I use `\cmidrule` in combination with `siunitx`? Is this even adviseable or not?
- Did I make an error somewhere else? The whole table looks so. freaking. weird.

I like the way the error (values are actually the confidence intervals but never mind) are parsed. But overall the rules put below AAA, BBB and CCC, I just do not get them. I also do not understand why the cmidrule below AAA goes way too far to the left? I'd *really* like to avoid the weird rule lengths and just have it as long as the vanilla command would produce it. :(

### Picture of status quo

[image]

### Picture of output with table-number-alignment=right

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
booktabs
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
per-mode=fraction,
locale=DE,
separate-uncertainty=true,
retain-explicit-plus,
binary-units,
%table-number-alignment=right
]{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lSSSS}
\toprule
{ValueA} & {VALUEb} & {AAA} & {BBB} & {CCC} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-5}
20 & 10 & -95,57(7) & 75,18 & -45,88 \\
& 20 & -142,72(12) & 89,20 & -58,62 \\
& 30 & -161,83(16) & -1118,51 & -75,19 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: by default I think it's centering on the decimal point, that's what it looks like from your image, the S column has assorted options to specify alignment though so you can change that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Edited op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorporating the minus signs in `table-format=…` and choosing `table-number-alignment=center` (the default is `center-decimal-marker`) will give an  acceptable result, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,booktabs}

\usepackage[per-mode=fraction, locale=DE, separate-uncertainty=true, retain-explicit-plus, binary-units, table-number-alignment=center, ]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcS[table-format=-3.2(2)]S[table-format=-4.2]S[table-format=-2.2]}%
\toprule
{ValueA} & {ValueB} & {AAA} & {BBB} & {CCC} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-5}
20 & 10 & -95,57(7) & 75,18 & -45,88 \\
& 20 & -142,72(12) & 89,20 & -58,62 \\
& 30 & -161,83(16) & -1118,51 & -75,19 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops! Completely overlooked that point. I'll update my answer at once.

Answer (score 3):

An `S` column needs refinements, the most common one is specifying the format of the numbers it contains; otherwise it does just some heuristics that usually don't work well.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
  lmodern,
  booktabs,
}


\usepackage[
  per-mode=fraction,
  locale=DE,
  separate-uncertainty=true,
  retain-explicit-plus,
  binary-units,
  %table-number-alignment=right,
]{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=-3.2(2)]
  S[table-format=-4.2]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
}
\toprule
{ValueA} & {VALUEb} & {AAA} & {BBB} & {CCC} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-5}
20 & 10 &   -95,57(7) &    75,18 & -45,88 \\
   & 20 & -142,72(12) &    89,20 & -58,62 \\
   & 30 & -161,83(16) & -1118,51 & -75,19 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the uncertainty in column 3. If you don't specify it, the uncertainty will not be displayed.

[image]

Use `S` for the preliminary version and fine tune it when you know the data are definitive.

Comment: Giving Bernard the checkmark because he was 2 minutes faster. Besides, he *really* seems to need it with his mere \approx 22k magic points against your 320k. ;)

Comment: @henry No problem for me; but I wanted to point out the uncertainty bit.

Comment: Noted that it is no problem and that you did not engage my joke. :( Also now I understand the little difference between your reply and Bernard's which actually makes you rreply better. And I would feel bad to take the magic points away from him and add them to your 320k.

Comment: @henry So feel good and leave them to him. ;-)

Comment: It just dawned on me that (in regards to the first uncertainty value) the value (7) is interpreted as 0.07. Or 7 percent, which is equally wrong for my data. Also I get an error when writing `table-format=4.2(2.2)` and supplying the data accordingly. Can I not do that?

Comment: @henry No, it is to say that the value is between `-95.57-0.07` and `-95.57+0.07`.

Comment: Hm, I see. So when I supply the data as `117.2(2.3)`, what are the options to parse that as `117.2+-12.3`? (or only "`+-12`" if one shouldn't parse the decimal value of the uncertainty part).

Comment: Meant `117.2(12.3)` of course...